# I want to assign a character value to a field that contains numbers without using CAST or CONVERT so as to avoid cardinality estimate warnings

Tags: sql-server, query, like

I'm looking at something like

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN MyField LIKE [0-9] THEN 'xyz'
WHEN MyField LIKE [10-99] THEN 'abc'
WHEN MyField LIKE [100-999] THEN 'def'
WHEN MyField LIKE [1000-9999] THEN 'ghi'
ELSE [pqr] END AS ACCOUNT_CATEGORY
FROM MyTable
```

The MyField is a datatype `smallint`, so does not have any numbers in it above 32,000.

Answer (score 2):

Then don't use `LIKE`. Compare your values to a numerical value. Also, as a `CASE` expression only returns the first TRUE result, you only need to include the upper boundary (though I include `0` in the first `WHEN` as you may have negative values):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN MyField >= 0 AND MyField < 10 THEN 'xyz'
            WHEN MyField < 100 THEN 'abc'
            WHEN MyField < 1000 THEN 'def'
            WHEN MyField < 10000 THEN 'ghi'
            ELSE [pqr] --Is this meant to be a column and not a literal string?
       END AS AccountCategory
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Alternatively you could use a lookup table with the boundaries, and `JOIN` to that. I use a `LEFT JOIN` to a `VALUES` table construct here, but it could be a physical table. The `LEFT JOIN` means that if no row is found you can return the value from your column `pqr`:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(V.AccountCategory,YT.pqr) AS AccountCategory
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN (VALUES(0,10,'xyz'),
                      (10,100,'abc'),
                      (100,1000,'def'),
                      (1000,10000,'ghi'))V(LowerBoundary,UpperBoundary,AccountCategory) ON YT.MyField >= LowerBoundary AND YT.MyField < UpperBoundary;
```